# Comparing strings with strcmp()

Tags: c++, string, compare, strcmp

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
const char *str1{"Jill"};
const char *str2{"Jacko"};
int result{std::strcmp(str1, str2)};

if(result < 0) {
std::cout << str1 << " is less than " << str2 << '.' << std::endl;
} else if(result == 0) {
std::cout << str1 << " is equal to " << str2 << '.' << std::endl;
} else {
std::cout << str1 << " is greater than " << str2 << '.' << std::endl;
} 
return 0;
}
```

> Output: Jill is greater than Jacko.

My newbie question is: how come it returns the else statement block affirming Jill is greater than Jacko? What method is used in strcmp to compare those strings? is it by total, pair of bytes, whatever characters?

Comment: You forgot to include `<cstring>`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. This is just a code example from the book I'm using to learn C++. Thanks!

Comment: Throw the book away and get a decent one - strcmp is C, not C++.

Comment: Well, I'm aware it refers to C, though the book doesn't quite mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 'J' is compared to 'J', they are equal. Then 'i' is compared to 'a', 
'i' > 'a'

Therefor,

```
Jill is greater than Jacko
```

Comment: Oh hey! I got it! So that it means I've to keep in mind 'ASCII' values?

Comment: I assume you mean ASCII characters. Generally, you let the compiler do that. You asked what `strcmp()` does. What else would a character string contain?